# LyX change font to smooth-looking vector font

Tags: fonts, lyx

I don't like the way Lyx typesets my documents. Letters look jagged around the edges. When I click Document>Settings>Fonts the only options I have available are Default, Roman, Sans Serif and Typewriter. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2.0 (beta) you’ll simply have to change the font in the respective drop down menus for ‘roman’, ‘sans serif’ and ‘typewriter’. I don’t know if it is the same in earlier versions.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the answer to the question "The fonts are bad in the exported PDF, what can I do?" in the [LyX FAQ](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/PDF) will help you. I suspect that you are using the default computer modern fonts, which are bitmap fonts optimized for printing, but they will look bad on the screen.  You need to switch to vector fonts if you want to produce document that will look good when viewed on screen.

Answer (score 1):

We solved this for our report by switching to `Latin Modern`... use **Latin Modern Roman**, **Latin Modern Sans**, and **Latin Modern Typewriter** and see if you see an improvement---we did!

(this is under the same Document>Settings>Fonts window)

Answer (score 0):

The answer in my distribution is **not** to change anything in LyX or LaTeX at all, but to change what is installed in the system.
On Ubuntu GNU/Linux, that is, I just installed the `cm-super` package (i.e. `sudo apt install cm-super`) and all of a sudden all my LyX documents, using the `default` font choice in LyX, were beautiful vector fonts, i.e. perfectly formed when zoomed in 1000% in the PDF.